# How do I show that $g(x)= d(x,f(x))$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Given:
$\bullet \ (M,d)$ is compact metric space
$\bullet \ f:M \to M \ $ such that $d(f(x),f(y))< d(x,y) \  $ for $x \neq y$

To show:
$g:M \to [0,\infty) \ $ with $g(x)= d(x,f(x))$ is continuous

Problem:
I would like to show this using the epsilon-delta definition:
Definition:
\begin{equation}
\text{Let} \  (M,d) \text{and} \  (N, \rho) \  \text{be metric spaces}\\
\text{and} \  f: M \to N \\
f \  \text{is continuous at a point x} \in M \ \text{if}:\\
 \text{For every} \ \epsilon >0 \  \text{there is a} \  \delta > 0 \  \text{such that} \\ \ \rho(f(x),f(y))< \epsilon \  \text{whenever} \  y \in M \  \text{satisfies} \    d(x,y)< \delta \end{equation}

In our problem $N$ is $[0,\infty)$, but what is then the metric $\rho$?
Should I use $\rho(x,y) = | x-y|?$
 Because then I would like to show $\rho(g(x),g(y)) = |d(x,f(x)) -d(y,f(y))| <\epsilon $
 but I can't figure this out.

Can someone show me how to show that g is **continuous**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since it is a subset of $\mathbb R$, you should use the "standard metric" for $\rho$ unless otherwise specified. Then you just need to use the triangle inequality

\begin{align}&|d(x,f(x)) - d(y,f(y)) | \\ &\le |d(x,f(x)) - d(x,f(y)) | + |d(x,f(y)) - d(y,f(y)) |  \\ &\le d(f(x),f(y)) + d(x,y) \\&\le 2d (x,y).\end{align}
Thus its even Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly the answer I was looking for: simple and to the point.

Comment: @Phoenix_10 glad to help! You should accept one of the answers to your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

First you should know that that the metric as a map $d: M \times M \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, where $M \times M$ has the product topology (or product metric, if you prefer), and $\Bbb R$ the standard topology. This is a standard fact proven many times over on this site.

Then $(1,f): M \to (x, f(x)) \in M \times M$ is also continuous when $M \times M$ has the product topology, as $\pi_1 \circ (1,f) = 1_M$ and $\pi_2 \circ (1,f) = f$ and the universal property of maps into a product.

You map is then just the composition $d \circ (1,f)$ and is thus continuous.

Comment: Indeed, this proof which I prefer also shows that its Lipschitz (since the composition of Lipschitz maps is also Lipschitz)